# In Sybase SQL, can multiple square brackets be avoided in a LIKE statement?

Tags: sybase

In Sybase SQL, I have a check that looks something like this:

```
SELECT "VALID"
WHERE @v_Test LIKE "X[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]"
```

Is there a way to avoid having to copy the square brackets please (in this case allowing alphanumeric values but anything is possible)?

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?

Comment: That's fair. Adaptive Server Enterprise, 15.7, I forget the SQL apart from Sybase Transact SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> { and }

> Left and right curly braces are metacharacters when used for specifying quantifiers. Quantifiers specify the number of times a pattern must repeat to constitute a match. For example:

> {m}   Matches a character exactly m times. For example, '519-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}' matches a phone number in the 519 area code (providing the data is formatted in the manner defined in the syntax).

> {m,}   Matches a character at least m times. For example, '[0-9]{5,}' matches any string of five or more digits.

> {m,n}   Matches a character at least m times, but not more than n times. For example, SIMILAR TO '_{5,10}' matches any string with between 5 and 10 (inclusive) characters.

see [manual](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/rf-sqllanguage-s-4915351.html)
So

```
SELECT "VALID"
WHERE @v_Test LIKE "X[A-Za-z0-9]{5}"
```

Comment: The {} brackets did work (as in were not illegal) but gave the wrong result....
Something that should have returned "VALID" returned nothing.

Comment: for that you should test the regular expression there are online sites for that, but i can't verify because i can't see the patterns you are looking for. but that was not the question

Comment: That's a fair request. I have been using a LIKE with the following string:
”GMR[A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z]”
That is GMR[A-Z][0-9A-Z]*8.

Comment: mysql statement searches for X aat the beigijng and exact 5 [0-9A-Z] if you have 8 you need to put there an 8 like i quoted in the answer and if you have variables sizes. but please [accept the answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: OP is using Sybase **ASE**; nbk's link is to a Sybase **SQLAnywhere** manual; **ASE** and **SQLAnywhere** are 2 completedly different products with different SQL dialects (ASE/TransactSQL vs SQLAnywhere/Watcom); in this case ASE does not provide support for the proposed answer of using `{5}` to designate a repeating pattern